# Joining two queries returns much more rows than expected?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, window-functions

I have the two queries. They both return around 60 rows. But after joining them, they return 900 rows. Is there a way to get the 60 rows while joining them.

Query 1:

```
SELECT 
    f.id_user,
    f.topup_date,
    f.topup_value,
    LEAD(f.topup_date) OVER (PARTITION BY(f.id_user) ORDER BY f.topup_date DESC),
    f.topup_date::timestamp - LEAD(f.topup_date::timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY(f.id_user) ORDER BY f.topup_date DESC),
    CASE WHEN f.topup_value >= 20 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' end,
    CASE WHEN f.topup_value >= 20 THEN LEAD(f.topup_date) OVER (PARTITION BY (f.id_user) ORDER BY f.topup_date DESC) END
FROM topups AS f
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(t2.topup_value as float)/CAST(t1.topup_value as float) 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t1.id_user,
        t1.topup_value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id_user ORDER BY t1.topup_date ) AS rowrank
    FROM topups t1 
) AS t1 
INNER JOIN topups t2 ON t1.id_user=t2.id_user
WHERE t1.rowrank = 1
GROUP BY
    t2.id_user,
    t2.topup_value,
    t2.topup_date,
    t1.topup_value,
    t1.rowrank
ORDER BY 
    t2.id_user,
    t2.topup_date DESC
```

Joined query:

```
SELECT 
    f.id_user,
    f.topup_date,
    f.topup_value,
    LEAD(f.topup_date) OVER (PARTITION BY(f.id_user) ORDER BY f.topup_date DESC),
    f.topup_date::timestamp - LEAD(f.topup_date::timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY(f.id_user) ORDER BY f.topup_date DESC),
    CASE WHEN f.topup_value >= 20 then 'Y' ELSE 'N' END,
    CASE WHEN f.topup_value >= 20 THEN LEAD(f.topup_date) OVER (PARTITION BY (f.id_user) ORDER BY f.topup_date desc) END,
    CAST(t2.topup_value AS float)/CAST(t1.topup_value AS float) 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t1.id_user,
        t1.topup_value,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.id_user ORDER BY t1.topup_date ) AS rowrank
    FROM topups t1
) AS t1 
INNER JOIN topups t2 ON t1.id_user = t2.id_user 
INNER JOIN topups f  ON f.id_user = t2.id_user
WHERE t1.rowrank = 1
GROUP BY 
    f.id_user,
    f.topup_date,
    f.topup_value,
    t2.topup_value,
    t1.topup_value,
    t2.id_user,
    t2.topup_date
ORDER BY 
    t2.id_user,
    t2.topup_date DESC, 
    f.id_user,
    f.topup_date DESC
```

Comment: Why are you joining on `id_user` only? Shouldn't you join on the complete `topups` key? Your second query Looks weird by the way. What is the `GROUP BY` clause for? I see no aggregation (`SUM`, `COUNT` or the like).

Comment: I entirely reformated your SQL queries to make them readble. Please consider using the same formatting rules for your next questions! Questions will long and unformated SQL code usually recieve less attention from the community...

Comment: @GMB Thank you very much..I'll remember it next time

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I just wanted to join the two queries , so i used id_user. Regarding the 2nd query, i need the output of certain columns in certain order according to each user id. There's no real meaning for it i guess. I'll remove it.

Comment: Think about which columns make a row unique in either query. Probably it's the `topups` primary key. Join on this column or these columns, so as to retain the row count.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner There's just id_user which makes a row unique . And there are total 5 user ids but these 5 ids have multiple topups ,hence in total 60 rows. But what im getting is 900 rows after joining them

Comment: The user ID makes a row unique? And there are five user IDs only? Then you can have five rows only. If you have sixty rows, then you need fifty different user IDs. Otherwise a user ID doesn't make the rows unique. What is topups primary key?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner oh,okay ..yes..i'll try that and let u know

Comment: @ThorstenKettner There's a 'seq' column with 68 unique values. I tried using this in join conditions, it gives just 5 rows with changed output. I need 68 rows here.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code plus desired output plus clear specification & explanation. Minimal means adding minimal problem code to minimal working code. So give minimal code that you show does what you expect & minimal code with the first place you go wrong. (Debugging fundamental.) Please clarify via edits, not comments. PS You don't even explain or illustrate what result you want. "get the 60 rows while joining them" is not clear. "just wanted to join the two queries" tells us nothing. Tell us exactly what a row tells you when it is in the result.

Comment: PS Don't give a [mcve] with 60 & 900 rows. Give minimal representative data. Preferably  show the subquery 2 value that goes into the final query or even use the value directly. And make the problem final join query as small as possible. PS DDL is going to be critical. Because PKs, UNIQUEs & FKs constrain the input & output of queries. PS Please don't use "join" to mean "combine" when your'e not combining by joining.

Comment: You haven't thought trough which rows to join actually. I've posted an answer to show what you seem to be missing here. (However, I am pretty sure one could write a much simpler query to get the result you are after. It should suffice to select from the `topups` table only once.)

Answer (score 0):

You want to join two query results. For each row in one query result you expect to find one row in the other query result. So, look at the first row in the first query result. You seem to want to join it with exactly one row in the second query result. Which row is this? Which columns do you compare in order to find this matching row?

Let's say these are your query results:

```
col1 | col4 | col7 | col6 | col3
-----+------+------+------+-----
A    | B    |  100 |  110 | E
A    | B    |   19 |   22 | E
F    | G    |   80 |   78 | H
F    | I    |   22 |   12 | J
```

and

```
col4 | col2 | col1 | col3 | col8
-----+------+------+------+-----
B    |  333 | A    | E    |   89
B    |  211 | A    | E    |   84
G    |  815 | F    | H    |   77
I    |  639 | F    | J    |   79
```

You want some result like this:

```
col1 | col4 | col7 | col6 | col3 | col4 | col2 | col1 | col3 | col8
-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----
A    | B    |  100 |  110 | E     | B    |  333 | A    | E    |   89
A    | B    |   19 |   22 | E     | B    |  211 | A    | E    |   84
F    | G    |   80 |   78 | H     | G    |  815 | F    | H    |   77
F    | I    |   22 |   12 | J     | I    |  639 | F    | J    |   79
```

but you are getting something like this instead:

```
col1 | col4 | col7 | col6 | col3 | col4 | col2 | col1 | col3 | col8
-----+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-----
A    | B    |  100 |  110 | E     | B    |  333 | A    | E    |   89
A    | B    |  100 |  110 | E     | B    |  211 | A    | E    |   84
A    | B    |   19 |   22 | E     | B    |  333 | A    | E    |   89
A    | B    |   19 |   22 | E     | B    |  211 | A    | E    |   84
F    | G    |   80 |   78 | H     | G    |  815 | F    | H    |   77
F    | G    |   80 |   78 | J     | I    |  639 | F    | J    |   79
F    | I    |   22 |   12 | H     | G    |  815 | F    | H    |   77
F    | I    |   22 |   12 | J     | I    |  639 | F    | J    |   79
```

You are getting such result, because you just picked one column to join the two query results (`id_user` in your case, `col1` in mine). Look at the first row of the first query result above. It has `col1 = 'A'`. If I join the second query result on `col1`, then there are two matching rows, because the second query result has two rows with `col1 = 'A'`. I end up with many more matches than I want.

So, what are the columns we want to match? In my example it is `col1`, `col3`, and `col4`. Look at the first row of the first query result again. It has `col1 = 'A' and col3 = 'B' and col4 = 'E'`. There is only one row in the second result set matching `col1 = 'A' and col3 = 'B' and col4 = 'E'`. My query would hence be

```
select *
from (<query 1 here>) q1
join (<query 2 here>) q2 on q2.col1 = q1.col1 and q2.col3 = q1.col3 and q2.col4 = q1.col4;
```

Or I would rather explicitly say which columns I want to see in my result and remove duplicate columns:

```
select q1.col1, q2.col4, q1.col7, q1.col6, q1.col3, q2.col2, q2.col8
from (<query 1 here>) q1
join (<query 2 here>) q2 on q2.col1 = q1.col1 and q2.col3 = q1.col3 and q2.col4 = q1.col4
order by q1.col1, q2.col4, q1.col7;
```